# ¿como puedo mandar a actualizar una variable de un codigo php a otro que solo se visualiza en un php principal sin abrir el php a consultar?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, variables, url, get

como puedo mandar a modificar una variable de fecha de un código PHP que solo recopila datos para una pagina PHP principal que solo los muestra, esto con el fin de hacer consultas a otras fechas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias dar un ejemplo mucho mas claro de lo que queres hacer?